# Choosing file path not seen on JTextField in Ubuntu on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtextfield, jfilechooser

I have this code (this is all code). I want to write file path(choosing file) on `JTextField`. I run the program and i press button and file chooser open, i choose file but file path not write on `JTextField`.

```
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Bilateral;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Constraints;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.GroupLayout;
import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts.Leading;


//VS4E -- DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!
public class xailabsPanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton jButton0;
    public static String path;
    private JTextField jTextField0;
    private static final String PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";

    public xailabsPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new GroupLayout());
        add(getJText(), new Constraints(new Bilateral(12, 12, 4), new Leading(100, 10, 10)));
        add(getJButton0(), new Constraints(new Bilateral(117, 117, 94), new Leading(57, 12, 12)));
        setSize(328, 252);
    }

    private JButton getJButton0() {
        if (jButton0 == null) {
            jButton0 = new JButton();
            jButton0.setText("jButton0");
            jButton0.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    jButton0MouseMouseClicked(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton0;
    }

    private JTextField getJText() {
        if (jTextField0 == null) {
            jTextField0 = new JTextField();
        }
        return jTextField0;
    }

    private static void installLnF() {
        try {
            String lnfClassname = PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            if (lnfClassname == null)
                lnfClassname = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfClassname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot install " + PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL
                    + " on this platform:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main entry of the class.
     * Note: This class is only created so that you can easily preview the result at runtime.
     * It is not expected to be managed by the designer.
     * You can modify it as you like.
     */

    private void jButton0MouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("home/kerim")));


        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            // user selects a file

            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().toString();

            jTextField0.setText(path);
    } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        installLnF();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                xailabsPanel frame = new xailabsPanel();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(xailabsPanel.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setTitle("xailabsPanel");
                frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(frame.getSize());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `JTextField` inside the method (and you are modfying its contents), but it's not added anywhere.

Drop `jTextField0 = new JTextField()` and it should work (assuming you already created the text field beforehand).

Comment: It doesn't work i drop jTextField0 = new JTextField() and i try again but result is same

Comment: Where and how are you creating the text field? Show the code.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine, when I do the following

- Change layout manager default `BorderLayout` (why? Because I don't have GroupLayout, it's not a standard Layout Manager - so I don't know if it's a direct cause)
- Add the componenst to corresponding BorderLayout positions.
- Changed `setSize()` to `pack()`. This is the preferred way.
- create the text field the the constructor (`new JTextField(int columns)`). For some weird reason I feel like this is the culprit (as without this, the text field has no preferred size, and maybe you just weren't seeing it. Not 100% sure, hell probably not even 50% sure, as I couldn't test the GroupLayout
- Got rid of `frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(frame.getSize());`, another suspected culprit (not really necessary to delete, but not preferred to keep).
- Got rid of this unnecessary line, as it's redundant `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);` and causing the file chooser to open twice.

Here's the result

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

//VS4E -- DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE!
public class xailabsPanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton jButton0;
    public static String path;
    private JTextField jTextField0;
    private static final String PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";

    public xailabsPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //setLayout(new GroupLayout());
        add(getJText(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(getJButton0(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        //setSize(328, 252);
        pack();
    }

    private JButton getJButton0() {
        if (jButton0 == null) {
            jButton0 = new JButton();
            jButton0.setText("jButton0");
            jButton0.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    jButton0MouseMouseClicked(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton0;
    }

    private JTextField getJText() {
        if (jTextField0 == null) {
            jTextField0 = new JTextField(20);
        }
        return jTextField0;
    }

    private static void installLnF() {
        try {
            String lnfClassname = PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            if (lnfClassname == null)
                lnfClassname = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfClassname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot install " + PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL
                    + " on this platform:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main entry of the class. Note: This class is only created so that you can
     * easily preview the result at runtime. It is not expected to be managed by
     * the designer. You can modify it as you like.
     */

    private void jButton0MouseMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        //fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        //fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System
                //.getProperty("home/kerim")));

        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            // user selects a file

            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().toString();
            System.out.println(path);

            jTextField0.setText(path);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        installLnF();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                xailabsPanel frame = new xailabsPanel();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(xailabsPanel.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setTitle("xailabsPanel");
                //frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(frame.getSize());
                ((JPanel) frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory
                        .createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never added JTextField to your JFrame (or whatever window you want the text field to be).

Right after your **JTextFIeld0 = new JTextField();** add: **myWindow.add(jTextField0)**

also, you are displaying two open dialogs. i dont think it is your desired behavior, remove the file **fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);**

Here is a quick example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // you should not need this, use the frame you already have, where the button is.
    JFrame window = new JFrame(); 

    // This is what you are doing in your code, however, you should add a text field
    // whereever you create and populate your jframe, and add the button etc, and simply
    // set the jtextfield value here
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();

    // again in your case you should have this somewhere else, i assume if you are
    // displaying a button, you must have a JFrame somewhere
    window.setSize(100, 100);
    window.add(tf);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    /***** you DO NEED this code **************/

    // create file chooser and open the dialog.
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    // get selected file object
    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();

    // disply file path in the text field
    tf.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());

    /****** end of the code you need *********/


    // display a JFrame with the text field (dont need this obviously you 
    // already are displaying the frame)
    window.setVisible(true);

}
```